# WM_SIZE: How to correctly parse lParam?

Tags: c, winapi

This question is incredibly specific.  When I read other C/C++ posts on SO.com, they are so severe about signed vs unsigned integral values.

The Win32 `WM_SIZE` message is defined as: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size

`LPARAM lParam`

> lParam
>
> The low-order word of lParam specifies the new width of the client
> area.
>
> The high-order word of lParam specifies the new height of the client
> area.

My platform is: 64-bit Win 10

This page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

... says: `typedef LONG_PTR LPARAM` -> `typedef __int64 LONG_PTR`

Type is `signed long long` (essentially: `<stdint.h>` -> `int64_t`)

I (wrongly?) assume to "split" `LPARAM` into two parts:

`WORD LOWORD(DWORD dwValue)`

^^^ Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632659(v=vs.85)

`WORD HIWORD(DWORD dwValue)`

^^^ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632657(v=vs.85)

But `WORD` is defined as `A 16-bit unsigned integer` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

This seems to incorrectly mix signed and unsigned integral types.  In my view, this is dreaded "UB" (undefined behaviour), but obviously millions of Win32 programs use this technique correctly.

What do I misunderstand?

Finally, please edit this question if better tags can be added, or the title/content can be improved(!).

Comment: What is left UB by the ISO standard, may be implementation defined and implemented to yield valid results on concrete implementations. MSVC is the de-facto standard for compiling WINAPI code. Other compilers aim to be compatible with MSVC when targeting windows. On the other hand, Microsoft has no interest on defining their API in a way that would work with some other compilers on some other platforms that Windows doesn't even run on. The bottom line is that whatever Microsoft says should work (here LOWORD/HIWORD to split an LPARAM), you can safely use when writing for Windows.

Comment: Not sure how you compile but the Windows SDK defines `LOWORD(l)` as `((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff))` (in minwindef.h) with `typedef unsigned short WORD;` and `typedef ULONG_PTR DWORD_PTR;` and `typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;` so 100% unsigned (in basetsd.h)

Comment: Don't ignore the fact that the documentation for both [`LOWORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632659(v=vs.85)) and [`HIWORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632657(v=vs.85)) is wrong. Those are (function-like) macros with untyped parameters (documented as being a `DWORD`). Since all documentation for macros is wrong (and has been, for years), this isn't much of a shocker.

Comment: One thing to note, particularly with WM_SIZE, is that a signed window size doesn't make any sense, unlike a signed window position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard, at least since C99, has to say this:

> ##### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type ... if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

Therefore the casting of signed to unsigned is well-defined, and produces the same value modulo `MAX_VALUE+1`. The exact meaning, as far as bits go, depends on the representation of integer values. On two's complement machines, this description simply leaves the bits (that fit) unchanged, and ignores the higher order bits if the new type is smaller.

---

None of it really matters though, because WINAPI is a very specific platform that's meant to be compiled with a very concrete compiler (MSVC). Therefore, if Microsoft intends you to use `LOWORD` and `HIWORD`, and "millions of programs" use them, you can be sure that these will work for their intended purpose on Windows, no matter if the ISO standard guarantees that or not.

Comment: Windows' ABI mandates two's complement representation of signed integer values. And with C23 putting an end to this madness by mandating that two's complement representation be the only allowed representation, it's unlikely to see much divergence in compilers in practice.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, that's kinda my point; I don't know of Windows ABI saying that explicitly anywhere, it's just that Windows doesn't run on anything else, so the hypothetical scenarios of 'what if' simply remain, err, hypothetical.

Comment: I'm not aware of a document that formally describes Windows' ABI. It's pretty much down to what [MSVC says it is](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220112-00/?p=106150).

Comment: So, in 64-bit systems, the higher 32 bits of lParam is unused? The documentation of HIWORD says it returns "the high-order word of the specified value", but the actual implementation seems to return the second word which is not the same thing as the high-order word for a 64-bit value.

Comment: @Plastic ["... of the specified 32-bit value"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632657(v=vs.85)). The signature also says that it expects a `DWORD` as a parameter. I'd say that the documentation is correct for 64-bit platforms too. Yes, the higher 32 bits are then unused.

Comment: The part I quoted is from the "Return value" section of the documentation. But fair enough. Thanks.